# Which command execute when I click on "Update the stack" button in Portainer?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

I use Portainer and have one stack.
As I see, click on "Update the stack" button will run command

```
stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file stackFilePath stackName
```

https://github.com/portainer/portainer/blob/develop/api/exec/swarm_stack.go#L71

Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portainer developer here, you're right.